# Kähler currents of Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ forms an open set in $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold, it is well known that the Kähler cone $\mathcal K$ forms an open set in $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$, see for example Huybrechts《complex geometry》p130. The proof is roughly like this: let {$e_1,e_2,..., e_n$} be a basis of $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$, $\omega$ being a Kähler class of $X$, then for $\lambda_i$ small enough, $\tilde\omega=\omega+\lambda_1e_1+...+\lambda_ne_n$ is also a real positive $d$ closed $(1,1)$ form, thus $\tilde\omega$ is also a Kähler class in the Kähler cone $\mathcal K$. So the Kähler cone is an open set in $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$.

And my question is, for a manifold in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$, which is bimeromorphic to a compact Kähler manifold, the cone determined by classes of the Kähler currents also forms an open set in $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$?

From [a paper of Demailly-Paun 04](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/kahlercone.pdf), a manifold is in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ if and only if it carries a Kähler current, that is a closed (1,1) current $T$ such that $T\geq\epsilon \omega$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and some smooth Hermitian form $\omega$(not necessarilly closed). So let currents {$e_1,e_2,...,e_n$} be a basis of $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$, but $\tilde T=T+\lambda_1e_1+...+\lambda_ne_n$ does not seem $\geq\epsilon\omega$ still, so does it means the cone formed by Kähler currents is not an open set in $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$?

In [DP04](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/kahlercone.pdf) page7 definition 1.6. A Kähler current $T$ has a class $[T]$ which lies in $\mathcal E$ and conversely any class $\alpha$ in the interior of $\mathcal E$, denoted as $\mathcal E^0$, can be represented by a Kähler current $T$, where $\mathcal E$ denotes the psuedo-effective cone in $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$. Does it means the cone of classes of Kähler currents is just $\mathcal E^0$ and it is open in $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$?

Comment: The current cohomology is isomorphic to the usual de Rham cohomology. So you can always represent a pertubation of the class $[T]$ by the current $T_\lambda:=T+\sum \lambda_i \alpha_i$ for $|\lambda|\ll 1$ and $\alpha_i$ smooth $(1,1)$-forms. In particular $T_\lambda$ is still a Kähler current.

Comment: @Henri, but Kähler current can not be represented by a Kähler form in the same $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$ right? So we still need to check that $T\geq\epsilon\omega$, right?

Comment: You simply represent $[T]$ by $T$.

Comment: @Henri, $T\geq \epsilon\omega$, but $T_\lambda:=T+\lambda\alpha$ for any $\alpha\in H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$,$|\lambda|<<1$, we need to check that $T_\lambda$ also $\geq\epsilon\omega$, right?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a (smooth) form, not a cohomology class. So $\varepsilon \omega+\sum \lambda_i \alpha_i \ge \frac{\varepsilon}2 \omega$ for small $|\lambda|$.

Comment: @Henri, Ok, it indeed make sense, does the classes determined by Kähler currents has a name? or jusk called the interior of pseudo-effective cone $\mathcal E^0$ as in Demailly and Paun's 04 paper?

Comment: You can call such a class a big class, but the terminology is not as standard as in the projective case.

Comment: @Henri, so a manifold in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ with $H^{0,2}(X)=0$ is Moishezon?

Comment: Yes, that's right.